# Rpy2 import package that overrides base function

Tags: python, rpy2

I currently try to use Rpy2 for using the `lme4` package combined with the `lmerTest` package. The latter extends/replaces the base `summary` function.

I use it the following way:

```
import rpy2.robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
r = rpy2.robjects.r
lme4 = importr('lme4')
lmerTest = importr('lmerTest')

m = lme4.lmer("a ~ b", data=data)
r.summary(m)
```

The main problem now is, that `summary` still uses the classic base function of `summary`, not the one provided by `lmerTest`. However, `lmerTest` does not directly provide an interface to the `summary` function but only overrides the base one. So, `lmerTest.summary(m)` does not work and produces an error.

I am looking for a way to make this work.

Comment: Where is `lmer`  coming from ?

Comment: sorry, comes from lme4

Answer (score 0):

A fancy way to interact with the S4 system can be

```
from rpy2.robjects.methods import importr
# R package to interact with the S4 system for OOP
methods = importr('methods')
# get the method with the wanted signature. 
my_summary = methods.getMethod("summary", signature="merMod")
# I assume the signature wanted to be `merMod`
# If not sure, you can do on you object `m`:
# tuple(m.rclass)
my_summary(m)
```

(see `getmethod` in action in rpy2's documentation: http://rpy2.readthedocs.org/en/version_2.7.x/robjects_oop.html#manual-r-in-python-class-definition ).

However, here I am suspecting that you either have created a function called `summary` in R's globalenv, or there is really no function `summary` for the object you want one for. (the example is not self-sufficient).

Comment: You have some errors in your code. The first line does not work. Also, the getMethod method does not work. Could you maybe tailor the answer towards the question?

Comment: @fsociety . Trivial typo (`import` instead of `importr`). The answer is what one can make without a self-sufficient example.

Answer (score 0):

The signature for `summary` is not *merMod*, but *merModLmerTest*, although *m* is of class *lmerMod*:

```
my_summary = methods.getMethod("summary", signature="merModLmerTest")
```